# Change color of li element based on array of strings

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my view I have list of statuses.

```
<ul>
    <li>FIRST_STATUS</li>
    <li>SECOND_STATUS</li>
    <li>THIRD_STATUS</li>
</ul>
```

In my model controller I retrieve updated statuses each second:

```
    $interval(function () {
            $scope.bad_statuses = Model.getStatuses({id: $scope.someModel.id});
    }, 1000);
```

`$scope.statuses` is an array of bad statuses, for `example $scope.bad_statuses[0]` = `FIRST_STATUS`. If status exists in `$scope.bad_statuses`, i want to color it red, otherwise - green.

So basically, somehow I need to retrieve each `<li>` value and based on condition if content from li existst in `$scope.bad_statuses` array, color it green or red.

How should I approach this problem? Im new to angularjs.

Comment: You can make a ngif expression which does this for you. Or use ngstyle to give a color to the text.

Comment: OR you can use ng-class for assigning different class based on expression.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made a plunkr for you, this should work :)

https://plnkr.co/edit/OP66yUB5lxBS5uCmtbRh?p=preview

Javascript code:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $interval) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.bad_statuses = ["FIRST_STATUS", "THIRD_STATUS"];
  $interval(function () {
            var lis = document.getElementById("list").getElementsByTagName("li");
            angular.forEach(lis, function(value, key){
               if($scope.bad_statuses.indexOf(value.innerHTML) > -1){
                 console.log("red");
                 value.style.color = 'red';
               }
               else{
                 console.log("green");
                 value.style.color = 'green';
               }
            });

  }, 1000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li ng-style="getColor(*status*)"></li>
```

In controller:

```
$scope.getColor = function(status) {
    return $scope.bad_statuses.indexOf(status) > -1 ? {color: 'red'} : {color: 'green'};
}
```

[Documentation for ng-style directive.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle)

Comment: `Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '*' not a primary expression at column 10 of the expression [getColor(*status*)] starting at [*status*)].`

Comment: You need to replace \*status\* with a string or a variable holding the status. It's a placeholder :)